# Java Play! 2 - User management with cookies

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to manage my user via cookie. It's not that easy because there is absolutely no documentation about this topic.

With the help of the sample "zentask" I made this:

```
session("username", filledForm.field("username").value());

public class Secured{

    public static Session getSession() {
        return Context.current().session();
    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        return getSession().get("username");
    }

    public static boolean isAuthorized() throws Exception {
        String username = getUsername();
        if (username == null)
            return false;
        long userCount = DatabaseConnect.getInstance().getDatastore()
                .createQuery(User.class).field("username").equal(username)
                .countAll();

        if (userCount == 1)
            return true;

        return false;

    }
```

I am using it like this:

```
public static Result blank() throws Exception {

        if (Secured.isAuthorized())
            return ok(Secured.getUsername());
        else
            return ok(views.html.login.form.render(loginForm));

    }
```

Now I have several questions/problems:

- 1.) Cookie is not dectypted and always looks the same. eg bdb7f592f9d54837995f816498c0474031d44c1a-username%3Akantaki
- 2.) What does the class Security.Authenticator do?
- 3.) I think user management through cookies is a very common problem, does play!2.0 offer me a complete solution? Or is there at least some documentation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is also full stack for `authentication` and `authorization` - [Play Authenticate](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/) by Joscha Feth. (available at [GitHub](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate))

It incorporates *ready-to-use* sample for Java, which uses concepts of `securesocial` + full [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) (by Steve Chaloner) support. it has:

- built in possibility to `register` and `log in` users with e-mail, Google, Facebook, Foursquare, Twitter, OpenId and custom providers.
- Multilanguage support (currently: English, German, Polish)
- Customisable templates (also for informational e-mails)
- Support for `roles` and `permissions` (via [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2))
- Password recovery support

There is sample app for Java in it. You can incorporate it to your app.

Comment: Just curious, could you give me a very brief overview what i need to change to make it work for Mongodb? I guess i would have to remove every sql method such as - play.find etc and replace it with morphia? I am just asking because I would need to change a lot. Don't want to make a huge mistake at the beginning

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you in topic `MongoDB` and `Morphia` I think it's best idea to start new question, addressing exactly the range of it.

Comment: @maik-klein there's a mongo db authentication library you can use https://github.com/ntenisOT/play-authenticate-mongo which used play authenticate

Answer (score 12):

As shown in the [Zentask sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Secured.java), your `Secured` class should extend `Security.Authenticator`.

With this, it will allow to put a `@Security.Authenticated` annotation either on a Controller, or on an Action. This annotation allows to redirect the client to another page if the user is not properly authorized (by overriding the `Security.Authenticator.onUnauthorized()` method).

The workflow is the following:

1. [Check authorization](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java#L19):
2. [Add an unique identifier in the client cookies](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java#L40)
3. [Check if authenticated](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Secured.java#L12)
4. [Secure a controller or an action](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Projects.java#L17)
5. [If not authorized, redirect the client to another page](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Secured.java#L17)

Comment: Yes thanks I already read through the zentask example. But in the zentask example , onUnauthorized() or getUsername() are never used, so i guess the playframework is calling them. How does play know when a user is authorized/ unauthorized?

Comment: Via the getUsername() method: returns null if the user is not authenticated  http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Security.Authenticator.html#getUsername(play.mvc.Http.Context)