# Play 2 authentication and authorization module

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am newbie to Play 2 framework. Can some one suggest a good user authentication and authorization module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This module is pretty awesome
http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/

Comment: The original question doesn't specify, but _play-authenticate_ is currently **Java-only**. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/PoQajClVx_8/cpxdG-L1m9YJ

Answer (score 9):

You can use SecureSocial: http://www.securesocial.ws. It provides Java and Scala APIs so you can use your preferred language.

Answer (score 2):

For Scala, I found https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth very easy to adopt. It has good examples and you get answers from the author rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely suggest play-authenticate I described it before, so here just the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11816859/1066240

note - it's better to base on the original Joscha's sample, my refactor  after discussion with the author will be modified soon, but now it's 'unstable'