# Play framework 2 authentication options

Tags: java, authentication, playframework-2.0

I am about to pick an authentication for Play 2 Java application. At the moment it would be simple username/pw and Facebook, backed with MongoDB.

It looks like there are two options: [securesocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial) and [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)

How do these compare? I can see both have support for common providers and based on a quick look play-authenticate seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play-authenticate is 'more advanced' it uses `securesocial's` base idea + additionally incorporates also `deadbolt-2` inside to give you full authenticate-authorization stack at once.

You wrote '*at the moment it would be simple...*' however you should think about this topic rather like '*finally it will be simple/advanced, so I need to choose correct solution at the beginning*'. And I'd suggest the PA.

See also [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11816859/1066240)

Comment: I would add that Play Authenticate comes with a sample Play! project giving you all the auth stuff implemented with no work. The one caveat I would caution people about is that Play Authenticate, and SecureSocial, which Play Authenticate is built on top of, are both one man projects. There is some risk of things falling behind. FWIW, I am using Play Authenticate, so I believe the added value is worth the extra risk.

Answer (score 4):

Play-authenticate was based on the design of SecureSocial.  Both modules provide authentication for  Play apps so I guess it's just a matter of trying both and see what works best for you.
SecureSocial is written in Scala and provides APIs in Java and Scala so you can use your preferred language with it.  Check the latest user guide at http://www.securesocial.ws.